# How can a very large JSON be parsed into a java object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

How can I convert json (gson or jackson, not important) to a json object with recursion elements?
Example of json: (each objects values can contain another object values)

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "name": "Name 1",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "Name 1.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert to a class of a kind

```
public class Simple {
    public List<ValuesEntity> values;

    public static class ValuesEntity {
        public String name;
        public List<ValuesEntity> values;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors have you gotten when trying anything?

Comment: Please note: Your inner objects are missing `"values"` keys

Comment: Yes, inner objects may not contain `"values"` keys.
> What errors have you gotten when trying anything? 
I don't know how to go through all entries in json when it have recursive items. Its not just loop

Comment: You don't need a loop yourself to serialize/deserialize. Gson and Jackson can convert your data within 3-5 lines of code...

Comment: Even when json file size about 50mb ?

Comment: I don't see why size really matters. You may get an OOM exception, but it's just a file parser.

Comment: if you really need to keep the memory footprint as low as possible, give a try to http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html (java version: https://github.com/s0cks/RapidJson-Java) which to be like SAX but for JSON. But your algorithm will be very different (conceptually) from a jackson-based.

Comment: Check this post. Could be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373233/is-there-a-saxparser-that-reads-json-and-fires-events-so-it-looks-like-xml