# Json + parse to find specific object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am working with a nasty API that returns complex JSON (more than 4200 lines) which includes multi dimensional arrays.
Some Objects are repeated,
in different locations of JSON.
For example:

```
"User":{
         "$id": "9",
         "Code": "NU",
         "DisplayName": "My Name",
         "Experience": 2.41
       },
```

Is there an easy way to parse entire JSON file and find list of Users?
Sometimes User is on the top level and sometimes it is nested in a four dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

No,
you will need to do work to achieve your goal.

### Some Details

This problem is not hopeless.
You can use an event-based JSON parser and ignore everything that is not related to the `User` object.

Here is a [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373233/is-there-a-saxparser-that-reads-json-and-fires-events-so-it-looks-like-xml) with answers.

Also,
try a google search for "json sax parser java" and you will find about a million links.

Another option might be to use JSON Xpaths.
Try a google search for "json xpath java".